# Is it possible to have different layouts for VF Pages? Eg. Printed Copy and Digital?

Tags: apex, visualforce, slds, page-layout, printable

Is it possible to have a different print view so I have functionality on paper?

This is the multi pick list form but once printed it has no functionality (Such as the scroll, I would just need check boxes.)

[image]

I would like the printed one to look like its designed for paper.

[image]
How can I change the view so it shows all values so a user can tick or circle an option? (Print View)

Im expecting to probably make a page that looks the same but where I substitute picklists for checkboxes.

Is this possible, if so how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In web development you can create CSS that is only used when printing is chosen.  Using display:none and other CSS you can add different sections to the page that are only displayed when printing is done.

Or you could create a link on your page called "print" that points to a new custom Visualforce page in which you change the layout for how you want.  That would include code to replace the picklists for checkboxes.

The second option is probably the easiest to work on compared to CSS styling an existing page for printing as it won't really be able to replace those fields.